# How to display contents which matches the path alias of a content from URL using views contextual filters?

Tags: views, path-aliases

I have a content type "basic" and have contents with different URL alias 
for ex:

> www.example.com/news/newsletter/title;
>
> www.example.com/content/title;

both are same type. I need to create a view page and the path for that view page is news/newsletter, In this page I want only the content which having the path alias news/newsletter. How can we get the content?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Views URL alias](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_url_alias)

> The 'Views URL alias' module allows Views to be filtered by path
>   aliases.
>
> This module is useful if your website uses heirachical paths. It
>   allows you to filter and sort a view by URL aliases.